# c# getting data from xml deserialized object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

hey guys i ran into a little problem when i was trying to deserialize an xml file,

the content of the xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Settings>
  <username>test</username>
  <password>test2</password>
</Settings>
```

and i have used visual studio's own special paste to make a class out of this:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class Settings {

    private object usernameField;

    private object passwordField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public object username {
        get {
            return this.usernameField;
        }
        set {
            this.usernameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public object password {
        get {
            return this.passwordField;
        }
        set {
            this.passwordField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

but now when i try to get the data using:

```
s.password.ToString();
```

the result i get is:

```
System.Xml.XmlNode[]
```

instead of the wanted: Test

how can i actually use the :

```
public object username {
        get {
            return this.usernameField;
        }
        set {
            this.usernameField = value;
        }
    }
```

to get the string returned that i think is being put inside.

EDIT!!!!

i actually got the values out by using:

```
XmlNode[] username = (XmlNode[]) s.username;
textBox1.Text = username[0].InnerText;
XmlNode[] password = (XmlNode[])s.password;
textBox2.Text = password[0].InnerText;
```

but there has to be a cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply declare the properties/fields as `string` rather than `object`:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Settings {
    private string usernameField;

    private string passwordField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string username
    {
        get
        {
            return this.usernameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.usernameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string password
    {
        get
        {
            return this.passwordField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.passwordField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

.NET serialization doesn't know what type of data it should expect when the members are declared as `object`, so it goes for the most general option of deserialization as an array of `XmlNode` objects.